# Change dimension of different objects in group to specific value

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have several circles of different Width and Height in a group. **How can I make them all 0.3mm W and H?**

I've found [this](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1197355) answer, which uses *Object > Transform > Transform Each...*
But that only allows to rescale each element in the group by a certain percentage,not absolute value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Ungroup everything
2. With all objects selected, go Effects > Convert to > Ellipses
3. Check Absolute and enter W & H values
4. Click OK
5. Option: Group back
6. Option 2: Object > Expand aspect

[image: ellipses]

Comment: Nice! It may also be worth while checking the script indicated in this [other question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11246/is-it-possible-to-specify-width-in-pixels-for-multiple-objects-at-the-same-time) if you're dealing with other objects than circles.